# Used space too close to allocated space for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

The following is a screen shot of what I see on the dashboard of my Azure SQL database. I did check the documentation on this so I do understand what each data point means. What I'd like to understand is whether it's problematic for the used space to be that close to allocated space.

The only data point I set is the max storage space and the rest are managed by Azure SQL Database so it should be OK but I don't want to make assumptions.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your allocated space will grow automatically, you don't have to worry about it, that is normal. You will always see used space close to allocated space. The key is when allocated space and used space are getting close to the maximum storage size.

If you see the database size reaching the maximum size you may need to run the following statement to increase the maximum size or adjust the maximum size using Azure portal.

```
ALTER DATABASE AzureDB2 MODIFY (EDITION='STANDARD', MAXSIZE= 50 GB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know from on-premise Data warehouse setups, you better enlarge the allocated space in larger chunks of the database than every time small chunks.. IMO you would like to tune the autogrowth when you want to insert large chunks of data.